# CakePHP Upgrade from 1.3.7 to 1.3.17

Tags: cakephp, upgrade

I have been working on a Cake project that was developed and setup by an outside company some time ago. It was setup with Cake 1.3.7 and seems OK for now.

I see that the 1.3 stream of Cake is now up to .17 and think it is about time I applied the update. But How??

I have googled for hours and can find masses of info on migrating to the V2 stream, but we are not ready to do that yet.

So how do I apply the latest patch of 1.3.17 to my environment? I thought it was just a case of replacing the cake folder with the new one but the .17 download has files in other places too, not just the cake folder.

Can anybody tell me what the process is to do this pls?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: you can safely ignore everything except for the "cake" core folder.

Comment: Great thanks. I will give that a go. I was just concerned that the zip file of the .7 upgrade had files from other locations too. Some of which have been altered for this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to replace [the cake folder](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/1.3/cake) with the new version.

Comment: Only that for 1.3 its directly "cake" (lib/Cake is 2.x).

Comment: I have marked this as the answer but mark was also right in his comment that for Cake 1.3 the folder is just 'cake'. But as there was not a full answer for that I couldnt mark it. Thanks to you both anyway.

Comment: Just a brief update. Replacing just the Cake folder did do the trick (in case anybody else out there is going to attempt this). BUT, we did get some strange results in the app. Search results not being shown etc. We are investigating the code to see what is different and what is causing it. Will post back when we find out what....